# How can I cancel the whole batch, not on first failure but after N th failure?

Tags: laravel

I have multiple batches that are using different 3rd party apis to get and store/update data. the connections are made via laravels http request. all batches have about 6k jobs. Because all jobs are important I need to log the failed ones and nofiy the user.

Sometimes the response returns an error for all jobs. sometimes just a connection error or an error because the server cant process those requests.

The batch automatically cancels on first failure. But is there a way to cancel the batch if there are multiple failues (on nth failure) not just first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First turn off normal batch error handling, then implement your own:

- Initialize a counter with zero.
- Whenever an error occurs, increase that counter.
- Whenever that counter reaches/exceeds 5, fail the batch.

The concise implementation depends on the batch system you are working with.

Comment: Okay I guess by " turn off normal batch error handling" you mean allowFailures(). Where should I implement this (counter) logic. In the class where I initilize the batch ? Can I put this logic in the catch() method of the batch?